# right usage of subject verb agreement: "There is only one of his novels that are/is interesting"

Tags: sentence-construction, subject-verb-agreement, restrictive-clauses

There **is** only one of his novels that** are** interesting.

Is this correct? If not which part is wrong, please tell me which explanation based on a sub-verb agreement.
In my book, it says **If a subject and the verb is joined by a relative pronoun, the verb used will agree with the antecedent to the relative pronoun( novels)**. Is this the case here?

Comment: The antecedent is "one"

Comment: **There is ... that is...** is unlikely. There's no need for "There is" in your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> One of his novels **is** interesting.

Hence,

> There is only **one** of his novels that **is** interesting.

Explanation: "that is interesting" is a restrictive [relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses), and it relates to the noun phrase "**one** of his novels". Basically, it relates to the word **one**.

---

We can use **are** here if we say that:

1. There is only one of his novels (in this room, or on the table).
2. By the way, his novels are interesting.

We would have to use a comma in this case:

> There is only one of his **novels**, which **are** interesting. (his novels are interesting)

---

We can also write the sentence this way:

> There is only one of his novels, which **is** interesting.

The meaning:

1. There is only one of his novels (in this room, on the table, or elsewhere).
2. This fact (that there is only one, and not more) is interesting.

Comment: Hey, thanks but there is a rule that says If a subject and the verb is joined by a relative pronoun, the verb used will agree with the antecedent to the relative pronoun( novels). Is this wrong rule?

Comment: @RitwikBhattacharyya - the rook is correct, but the antecedent in your sentence is "one"

Comment: I mean the **rule** is correct ))

Comment: Please clarify me if y understanding is correct. generally, the antecedent is the part directly before the relative pronoun. But as it is a kind of phrase 'one of the novels' so the relative pronoun relates with the main part of the phrase 'one'

Answer (score 0):

> There is only one of his novels that *is* interesting.

Other examples:

> This is one of the pens that *are* available.
>   This is only one of the pens that *is* available.